# MySQL Case When Count, using custom groups

Tags: mysql, count, case

I'm trying to figure out how to count how many instances of each of the three groups i've created in this query occur:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN idStatus=6 THEN "Accepted"
WHEN idStatus in (7,8) THEN "Denied"
WHEN idStatus in (1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14) THEN "Working" END AS 'Claim Status'
FROM claims
WHERE Date > '2013-01-01'
```

I want a result that has two columns, "Claims status" and "Count", and has each of my three groups listed below with their counts from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "wrap" your query in another select statement, then performance will significantly decrease. You should group by the field you're calculating:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN idStatus = 6 THEN "Accepted"
    WHEN idStatus IN (7,8) THEN "Denied"
    WHEN idStatus IN (1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14) THEN "Working"
END AS ClaimStatus,
COUNT(*) ClaimCount
FROM claims
WHERE Date > '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY ClaimStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your query with an outer query to do the grouping:

```
SELECT claim_status AS 'Claim Status', COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN idStatus=6 THEN "Accepted"
        WHEN idStatus in (7,8) THEN "Denied"
        WHEN idStatus in (1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14) THEN "Working" 
    END AS claim_status
    FROM claims
    WHERE Date > '2013-01-01'
} t
GROUP BY claim_status
```